# I am trying to install devkitPro with pacman in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04, pacman

I am trying to install devkitPro in Ubuntu 18.04, and they are indicating that the packages are available using `pacman` package manager. I have installed `pacman` with the command `sudo apt install pacman`.

They are indicating about using the command `pacman-key --init` too, but when I have attempt to use `pacman-key`, I get the message `pacman-key: command not found`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `deb` file here: https://github.com/devkitPro/pacman/releases/download/devkitpro-pacman-1.0.1/devkitpro-pacman.deb

Download it via:

```
wget https://github.com/devkitPro/pacman/releases/download/devkitpro-pacman-1.0.1/devkitpro-pacman.deb
```

Install it via:

```
dpkg -i devkitpro-pacman.deb
```

This particular step will take a bit to complete but hang on. It will finish in several minutes:

gpg: Generating pacman keyring master key...

After it's done,

```
dkp-pacman -S switch-dev
```

You can replace `switch-dev` with whatever system for which you want to develop.

Log out and back in and the directory containing the binaries will be added to you path via `/etc/profile.d/devkit-env.sh`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I got these packages installed already.

Comment: I found that at the end of  

```bash
dkp-pacman -S switch-dev
```

the .sh files in `/etc/profile.d` folder are missing the execution flag (`chmod +x ...`)

Comment: @JoséRobertoGarcíaChico They do not need to be executable. They are sourced just like `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

And now you can use official installer.

```
wget https://apt.devkitpro.org/install-devkitpro-pacman
chmod +x ./install-devkitpro-pacman
sudo ./install-devkitpro-pacman
sudo dkp-pacman -S switch-dev

export DEVKITPRO=/opt/devkitpro
export DEVKITARM=${DEVKITPRO}/devkitARM
export DEVKITPPC=${DEVKITPRO}/devkitPPC
export PATH=$PATH:${DEVKITPRO}/tools/bin
```